# How to synchronize comments between WordPress and Facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments, synchronization

I import my WordPress posts into my Facebook account as Notes. I end up having two separate sets of comments for the same blog post this way.

Is there any way to do a two-way synchronize of these comments?

Does the Comment Box (Facebook social plugin) accomplish this?

Meaning.. if someone leaves a comment on the imported note in Facebook, would it appear in the comments list in Facebook if I used the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible.

The best way would be to just share your post summary as a status update and basically have the users click to the your blog to read more.

This is the reason the whole Graph API/Facebook Connect came out and everyone started using the like plugin.

Also to support why I do not think this is possible is the case of [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/). They are a Wordpress.com VIP member and I have not seen any feature like this on their site.

Comment: About TechCrunch, I think they do not do that because they do not want to do. Not all posts are replicated to Facebook, and comments on Facebook status are "lighter" than ones in their website.

But it is possible to sync, with your own app with read/write comments permission in your Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Backtype Connect](http://www.backtype.com/plugins/connect) on my WordPress blog to pull in comments from FriendFeed, Digg, and Reddit as well as mentions in Twitter.  It doesn't appear to support Facebook, however.