# Is there a way to 2way sync Facebook and self hosted WordPress blog comments

Tags: facebook, wordpress, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to synchronize comments between Wordpress and Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/how-to-synchronize-comments-between-wordpress-and-facebook)

Is there a way to 2 way sync blog and Facebook comments.

Use case: I post on my self hosted WordPress blog. I then share that to my Facebook fan page which puts the post on my wall. All comments on the blog post should show on the Facebook fan page as comments on the wall under the share and visa versa - all comments on the Facebook fanpage regarding that post should show up as comments on the blog post.

I am using WordPress specifically

I do not want to do this as notes, this to be done as a shared item on the fan pagewall

Comment: I can see this work for the Facebook to WordPress part (as long as you can read the Facebook comments with your app), but how should it work in the other direction? As what user should the comments from the WordPress side be posted on Facebook?

Comment: This maybe what you're looking for http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14133

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so.
That comes down to [comment ownership](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/how-do-you-take-ownership-of-your-comments).
A user allowed the posting of their comment on your page/blog not both.

Comment: I am not sure this is a comment ownership issue. The comments are on my Facebook wall already, I want them to be imported into my blog as that's what the comments are about. And visa versa I want my blog comments imported into Facebook. The idea is that a reader can read and interact in either place and see the entire conversation. Right now there are 2 separate conversations going on for each of my blog posts. 1 on the blog and 1 on Facebook. I simply want to merge the 2 conversations into one.

Answer (score 2):

have you looked into Facebook's social plugins, it might not be exactly what you are looking for, but might be a start http://www.watkissonline.co.uk/wordpress/?p=3274

Answer (score 2):

I've built something that does almost exactly this.

my.syyn.cc

It's very alpha (eg: note the almost total lack of web design).

It can't work with a facebook fan page, but it can work with your wall. You authorise it to talk with your wordpress, and your facebook, and it'll sync posts in one or both directions (you just want wordpress->facebook, not the other way) and it'll sync comments in both directions.

One point; I built it originally to do Facebook <-> Google Buzz (support for both of which is totally solid). The Wordpress support is brand new, and a bit tetchy; you'll get some comments going from Facebook to Wordpress and then reflected back to facebook again by mistake. I'll be sorting that out in the next couple of days, but it's manageable anyway now by simply deleting extra comments.